# Were the Bavarian Illuminati actually Luciferians?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, history-of-philosophy

According to wikipedia the real [illumianti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminati) were:

> ...the Bavarian Illuminati, an Enlightenment-era secret society founded on 1
>   May 1776. The society's goals were to oppose superstition,
>   obscurantism, religious influence over public life, and abuses of
>   state power...

According to wikipedia [Luciferianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciferianism) is (not to be confused with [Satanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satanism)):

> ...a belief system that venerates the essential
>   characteristics that are affixed to Lucifer. The tradition, influenced
>   by Gnosticism, usually reveres Lucifer not as the devil, but as a
>   liberator, a guardian or guiding spirit,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminati) or even the true god as
>   opposed to Jehovah...

This is similar to the idea of [Prometheus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus) who was punished by Zeus because he gave to mankind the technology of fire.

In popular culture we have seen many of movies such us [Bladerunner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner), [Prometheus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_(2012_film)), [The Devil's Advocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil%27s_Advocate_(1997_film)), [Lucy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucy_(2014_film)), [Transcendence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_(2014_film)) and large etc. that show this [free-mason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemasonry) symbolism and the underlying idea of the Christian creator god being in fact the devil.

Knowing the amount of disinformation and conspiracy theories on this matter **are there any credible sources that link this group of people with [Luciferianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciferianism)** or as many other intellectuals of their time they were just atheist?

Comment: Completly non-sensical : [the Illuminati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminati) - if real - were an Enlightenment-era secret society founded on 1 May 1776. The society's goals were to oppose superstition, obscurantism, religious influence over public life". Thus, if they opposed superstition and obscurantism how they can rever Lucifer ? And what is the link from an Enlightenment-era secret society and pop-culture movies ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "if real??" are you questioning the validity of the wikipedia article and its references? There has been other secret societies such us "Skull&Bones" linked to occultism. I want to know abut this historical secret society in the past.

Comment: Well, they shared interests with luciferians, but it's like to say Lucifer himself is luciferian. Which is odd.

Comment: @rus9384 I have added references and needed explanations. Most people here seem unable to tell between "conspiracy" and real fact because of personal prejudices.

Comment: I don't say about conspiracy. But you are commiting a fallacy here. Many people like freedom, are against religion, government, etc. And they can be in awe of Lucifer when they acknowledge his story. But if they are not aware of his story, they cam't be luciferians if they share his thoughts.

Comment: @rus9384 it's not conspiracy it's "ignorance". Many of these conspiracy theories are based on some truth. You need to be sharp-sighted that's all. Luciferism was also a way to protest the religion manipulation of the era. Some intellectuals realized this as It had happened in the past. Also some people accepted some of these ideas because they suited the way they felt. Not everybody liked the idea of a God banning you from heaven because you wanted "knowledge"

Comment: I agree with what you say. But at first, definition of luciferianism involves the fact that you believe in Lucifer and that what he did is right. While "oppose superstition, obscurantism, religious influence over public life, and abuses of state power" does not explicitly state it. There is bigger chance that masons called themselves after Hermes (which can be translated as mason), but illuminati do not have any explicit reference to Lucifer.

Comment: @rus9384 I want to get further than wikipedia. I'm investigating the references in both articles. Perhaps this network is not the right one for these questions. Thank you.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA. Your opening comment is, as so often, spot on, and I acknowledge this in my answer. My answer merely adds detail.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas I don't think Mauro was right this time. This question is most likely to be **censured** soon because of the **ignorance and mockery** of this subject. It's not the first time this happens in these forums. In fact I expected it. Bavarian Illumianti and  Luciferian Freemasons are perhaps just 50 years away. Not everybody who is interested in these subject is an Alex Jones fan. Thanks again for your answer

Comment: @PbxMan. I chiefly meant that I agreed with 'The society's goals were to oppose superstition, obscurantism, religious influence over public life'. Not so ? Best - Geoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bavarian Illuminati had no connexion with Luciferianism so far as I can ascertain, if 'Luciferianism' implies veneration of or respect for Lucifer.

My immediate source is a review of Vernon Stauffer's  New England and The Bavarian Illuminati :

> Well-entrenched tradition has asserted that the secret force
>    responsible for the New England [civil] disturbances [in the late 18th century] was the Bavarian
>    Society of the Illuminati. In the third chapter, therefore, the
>    author discusses the life of Adam Weishaupt, founder of the
>    Illuminati. He shows how, after "an educational experience
>    which had made him a passionate enemy of clericalism, Weishaupt, Professor of Law at the University of Ingoldstadt, arrived
>    at the conclusion that a general offensive against the clerical party
>    ought immediately to be undertaken . . . to overthrow
>   the forces of superstition and error." He would found a model
>    secret organization, "comprising 'schools of wisdom,' . .
>    wherein those truths, which the folly and egotism of priests
>    banned from the public chairs of education, might be taught
>    with perfect freedom to susceptible youths." On May 1, 1776,
>    the organization was founded. Under Weishaupt's sole domination, the Order was stagnant. With the accession, however, of
>    Baron Knigge, a Freemason of high degree, progress resulted,
>    and eventually an alliance with Freemasonry was effected.
>    Internal dissension, the scandalous lives of the leaders, and
>    political intrigues brought about suppression at the hands of the
>    Bavarian Government. On August 16, 1787, the Duke of
>    Bavaria "launched his third and last edict against the system.
>    The measures taken against the Order in Bavaria effectually
>    counteracted and destroyed its activities in other countries. (Joseph A. Murphy, The Catholic Historical Review, Vol. 5, No. 2/3 (Jul. - Oct., 1919), 265-270 : 267-8.)

Weishaupt clearly regarded the mainstream Christian churches as harbouring and spreading error, superstition, folly, and egotism. None of this suggests the least velleity towards Luciferianism. Indeed, I should imagine Lucifer was to be dispatched along with other clerical superstitions. (In this I wholly concur with Mauro Allegranza's opening comment, which can hardly be bettered.)

HISTORICAL NOTE

'Luciferianism' can also refer to 'the sect founder by Lucifer, bishop of Cagliairi in the 4th cent. AD, who opposed the supposed leniency of the Church towards epentant Arians' (Oxford English Dictionary). I assume these are not the Luciferians you have in mind.

REFERENCES

Vernon Stauffer, NewEngland and the Bavarian Illuminati. Vol. LXXXII of Studies in History, Economics and Public Law by The Faculty of Political Science. New York: Columbia University Press, 1918.

Review by: Joseph A. Murphy
Source: The Catholic Historical Review, Vol. 5, No. 2/3 (Jul. - Oct., 1919), 265-270.

Hardly recent sources but I have been unable to find anything later.

Comment: I was researching [Albert Pike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Pike) and his famous Luciferian [quote](https://albertpike.wordpress.com/albert-pike-lucifer/) It seems there is nothing linking the original secret society with the late luciferian Freemasons.

Comment: PbxMan. Our views coincide, then. Many thanks for letting me know the origins of your question. I hope your research is working out well. Best - GT.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a much better case from what you quote for atheism or deism. Luciferianism has always existed more as a smear than a coherent theology, and there is a history of trying to apply it to discrediting freemasonry https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxil_hoax

The only serious attempt I know of to examine what the self-declared Illuminati were historically, is Niall Ferguson's in "The Square and the Tower: Networks, Hierarchies and the Struggle for Global Power". There is quite a detailed discussion of this part of the book in the Waking Up podcast episode #117 "Networks Power and Chaos" https://youtu.be/w0TwPma4A2c

Umberto Eco's "Foucault's Pendulum" is a work of fiction that illustrates the way the idea of secret and hidden societies can become a screen to project ourselves on, and a tar baby to absorb energy and creativity.